# Can't do a loop cut or anything else with new version

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I can't even do a simple loop cut with the newest version of blender. Same goes for a lot of other functions because of an extra box that appears at the bottom left of the screen.I can't click a button to initiate the loop cut. Been trying out version 2.9 for a week and can't get any of the functions to work.

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6

Comment: Loop cuts don't work on triangles? IFAIK they never did? They only work on quads. Once you figure out how to use it, that popup box can be pretty awesome

Comment: it's not the Operator box (bottom left pop-up you're talking about) that prevents you to create loop cuts, as Ron Jensen says, it's the fact that apparently your topology is made of triangles, not quads